# Is the set of all polynomials mapping $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ a closed set?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials

I know that by Weierstrass Approximation, P([0,1],R) is dense in C([0,1],R).
But what about the case for P(R,R). Is it a closed set? I can't find any hint anywhere.

Comment: I mean, closed in F(R,R)

Comment: As the introductory materials and help pages indicate, please set your question with the proper markup.

Comment: What is $F(R,R)$?

Comment: set of all functions mapping R to R

Comment: You can't possibly expect polynomials to be dense in $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, as the typical function isn't even continuous at a single point.

Comment: I am not asking density in F(R,R), but in itself.

Comment: What topology are you putting on $F(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$? Pointwise convergence? In that case, $P(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ would not be closed.

Comment: Sorry, I neglected. Uniform convergence.

Comment: uniform convergence on compact sets? or uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: On R. But I am not sure I have understood what you have intended.

Comment: The two most commonly used topologies on $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ are the pointwise convergence topology and the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets. In the pointwise convergence topology, $f_n\to f$ if $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  In the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets, $f_n\to f$ if for every compact set $K$, $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $K$.